# Java Password Protect SQLite Database using JDBC

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I'm using SQLite JDBC (org.sqlite.JDBC) and I was wondering how do I encrypt or password protect my database?

I need it secured so only my application can acces the data.

Comment: Do you know about http://sqlcipher.net/ Basically it's SQLite with data encryption.

Comment: You could use the jasypt library: http://www.jasypt.org/encrypting-binaries.html, or create your own encryption/decryption class that would ask the user for a password and store the unpacked database to /tmp or something. The problem is that your DB would be unencrypted while you are running your application.